# ios Restkit - Mapping objects with a list within another list

Tags: ios, json, object, mapping, restkit

I'm trying to map objects using Restkit. I have no problems mapping normal JSON responses. In this case i have a problem because I want to map a response with this configuration:

```
{
    "id": 161,
    "text": "usertest",
    "test": {
        "id": "1",
        "beginDate": "17/04/2013",
        "expectedDuration": "45 minutes",
        "finishDate": "17/04/2013",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": 71,
                "text": "some text",
                "number":"number"
            },
            {
                "id": 81,
                "text": "some anothertext
            }
        ]
        ...
}
```

As you can see, I have a main object with three attributes(id, text and a list of tests). Each test has some attributes(id, beginDate,...,). Each test has also a list of groups. And here is my problem. When i try to map this, restkit can't map the 'groups' list.

I'm mapping this with this code:

```
//### TEST
RKEntityMapping *testCompleteMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"UserTest" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[testCompleteMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"id":             @"usertestID",
 }];

RKEntityMapping *usertest_TestMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Test" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[usertest_TestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"id":             @"testID",
 @"beginDate":            @"beginDate",
 @"expectedDuration":@"expectedDuration",
 @"finishDate":         @"finishDate",
 }];

RKRelationshipMapping* usertest_Test_Relationship = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"test" toKeyPath:@"test" withMapping:usertest_TestMapping];

//### GROUPS

RKEntityMapping *groupTestMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"QuestionGroup" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[groupTestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"id":             @"groupID",
 @"number":            @"number",
 @"text":@"text",
 }];

RKRelationshipMapping* group_Test_Relationship = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"groups" toKeyPath:@"groups" withMapping:usertest_TestMapping];


//### ADD PROPERTY MAPPINGS 

RKResponseDescriptor *CompleteTestResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:testCompleteMapping pathPattern:@"/api/module/demo2/lesson/Phasellus/test/71" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];


[testCompleteMapping addPropertyMappingsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:usertest_Test_Relationship, nil]];
[usertest_TestMapping addPropertyMapping:group_Test_Relationship];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:CompleteTestResponseDescriptor];
```

I also tried to use "test.groups" instead of "groups" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below. You're main issue appears to be a typo (in the definition of `group_Test_Relationship`), you are also missing some identification attributes (not strictly required) but generally the code is on the correct path.

You didn't show your definition of `testCompleteMapping` so you'll need to add that and check for typos.

```
//### TEST

RKEntityMapping *usertest_TestMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Test" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[usertest_TestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"id": @"testID",
 @"beginDate": @"beginDate",
 @"expectedDuration": @"expectedDuration",
 @"finishDate": @"finishDate",
 }];
 usertest_TestMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"testID" ];

//### GROUPS

RKEntityMapping *groupTestMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"QuestionGroup" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[groupTestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"id": @"groupID",
 @"text": @"text",
 }];
 groupTestMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"groupID" ];

[usertest_TestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"groups" toKeyPath:@"groups" withMapping:groupTestMapping]];


// complete your 'testCompleteMapping' here, adding the 'test' relationship property mapping to 'usertest_TestMapping' if required


//### ADD PROPERTY MAPPINGS 

RKResponseDescriptor *completeTestResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:testCompleteMapping pathPattern:@"/api/module/demo2/lesson/Phasellus/test/71" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:completeTestResponseDescriptor];
```

Comment: I forgot to show the definition of testCompleteMapping and to show the right code of JSON (there is a number field). Now, everything is right. I will try your code soon.

Comment: You were right. i made a mistake creating the realtionship.[usertest_TestMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"groups" toKeyPath:@"groups" withMapping:groupTestMapping]]; this line solve my problem.